# Why _.map iteratee's arguments is (value, key) not (key, value)?

Tags: functional-programming, underscore.js

According to the doc,

> If list is a JavaScript object, iteratee's arguments will be (value, key, list).

I constantly have to check the doc to verify the order. Why is `value, key` not `key, value`?

**[EDIT]**

I guess I'm (always) confused because the for loop in CoffeeScript iterates on `key, value`:

```
yearsOld = max: 10, ida: 9, tim: 11

ages = for child, age of yearsOld
  "#{child} is #{age}"
```

Comment: Are you asking for reasons why the creator of the library did it this way? Why don't you ask them directly instead? Otherwise I'm not sure what kind of answer you expect. "It's this way because someone decided to do it this way."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `value` is the more important, and most generic part of [mapping over structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)). Maybe not so much with `_.map` over objects, but when you `map` over arrays you typically use a unary function (which takes only the value). The index (or key) is hardly ever used, so it became the second argument that is usually omitted from the parameter list.